# ReactiveUI ObservableAsProperty not notifyin UI

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I am learning to use ReactiveUI in WPF.

I have run into problem, as this ObesrvableProperty NavigationItems doesnt update UI, but WhenAnyValue fires if I set breakpoint and check the .Select

My DI:

```
  Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new WindowsAuthenticationService(), typeof(IWindowsAuthenticationService));

  Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant<INavigatorService>(new NavigatorService(Locator.Current.GetService<IWindowsAuthenticationService>()));

  Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new MainWindowViewModel(Locator.Current.GetService<IWindowsAuthenticationService>(),
                                                                            Locator.Current.GetService<INavigatorService>()));
```

My binding:

```
 this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.NavigatorService.NavigationItems, v => v.SideNavigator.Items, s => s.ToList());
```

My MainViewModel

```
  public MainWindowViewModel(IWindowsAuthenticationService windowsAuthenticationService, INavigatorService navigatorService)
        {
            WindowsAuthenticationService = windowsAuthenticationService;
            NavigatorService = navigatorService;
            try
            {
                WindowsAuthenticationService.AuthenticateUser();
            }
            catch (UserNotRegisteredException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Navigator service

```
  public class NavigatorService : ReactiveObject, INavigatorService
    {
        public NavigatorService(IWindowsAuthenticationService windowsAuthenticationService)
        {
            WindowsAuthenticationService = windowsAuthenticationService;
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.WindowsAuthenticationService.AccessibleComponents)
                    .SelectMany(s => s ?? new List<TPermissionComponents>())
                    .Select(s => new FirstLevelNavigationItemWithValue() { Icon = s.Icon, Label = s.Name, Value = s.Component })
                    .ToList()

                    .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.NavigationItems, new List<FirstLevelNavigationItemWithValue>());
        }

        public IWindowsAuthenticationService WindowsAuthenticationService { get; }

        [ObservableAsProperty]
        public IEnumerable<BaseNavigationItem> NavigationItems { get; }
    }
```

And finnaly auth service:

```
  public class WindowsAuthenticationService : ReactiveObject, IWindowsAuthenticationService
    {
        public TUsers CurrentUser { get; set; }

        [Reactive]
        public IEnumerable<TPermissionComponents> AccessibleComponents { get; set; }

        public void AuthenticateUser()
        {
            var user = GetCurrentUser();
            if (user is null)
                throw new UserNotRegisteredException(Environment.UserName);
            CurrentUser = user;
            AccessibleComponents = GetAccessibleComponents(user);
            return;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TPermissionComponents> GetAccessibleComponents(TUsers user)
        {
            using AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext();
            var components = from assigment in ctx.TPermissionAssignment
                             join permission in ctx.TPermissions
                                    on assigment.RoleId equals permission.RoleId
                             join component in ctx.TPermissionComponents
                                    on permission.ComponentId equals component.Id
                             where assigment.UserId == user.Id
                             select component;
            return components.ToList();
        }

        public TUsers GetCurrentUser()
        {
            if (CurrentUser is null)
            {
                using AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext();
                return ctx.TUsers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Username.ToLower() == Environment.UserName.ToLower());
            }
            else
            {
                return CurrentUser;
            }
        }
```

I hope someone can help me, I am clueless for past 4 hours.

I will be glad for any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes to the same issue. This solved it to me:

```
   public NavigatorService(IWindowsAuthenticationService windowsAuthenticationService)
        {
            WindowsAuthenticationService = windowsAuthenticationService;
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.WindowsAuthenticationService.AccessibleComponents)
                    .Select(s => new ObservableCollection<FirstLevelNavigationItemWithValue>((s ?? new List<TPermissionComponents>()).Select(s => new FirstLevelNavigationItemWithValue() { Icon = Enum.Parse(typeof(PackIconKind), s.Icon, true), Label = s.Name, Value = s.Component })))
                    .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.NavigationItems, new ObservableCollection<FirstLevelNavigationItemWithValue>());
        }

        public IWindowsAuthenticationService WindowsAuthenticationService { get; }

        [ObservableAsProperty]
        public IEnumerable<BaseNavigationItem> NavigationItems { get; }
```

Be noted, that if ObservableAsProperty is setup like this:

```
        [ObservableAsProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<BaseNavigationItem> NavigationItems { get; }
```

Then the `ToPropertyEx` will freak out and wont compile.

My initial thought was the `.WhenAnyValue().ToPropertyEx()` would spit out every time new collection and that would trigger the binding.

Now I understand it like the `.WhenAnyValue().ToPropertyEx()` creates sort of pipeline throught which each object (entity) goes only once.

I my assumption is correct, then I would love to know, if it is more profitable performance wise, than spitting new collection each time.

Anyway, I hope this will help someone.